# SQLITE3 Importing .csv Files with Different Number of Columns

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, sqlite

I have thousands of `.csv` files where each row can contain either 18 or 23 columns. Sometimes a file contains some rows with 18 columns, and some rows with 23 columns.

I'm using a bash script to run a for loop and import each file to a sqlite3 database by running:

```
sqlite3 options.db ".mode csv data" ".import '$f' data"
```

And my database schema has 23 columns.

**Problem:** when `sqlite3` encounters a row with only 18 columns, it prints on terminal a message saying `expected 23 but found 18 - filling the rest with NULL`, and then proceeds to the next row. The rows are saved, but terminal has to print a message for each row, and since there are millions of rows, it slows down the importing process by a lot.

**Question:** How can I suppress the warning message from `sqlite3`? If I cannot suppress it, how can I avoid it in the first place?

Thanks for helping! :D

Comment: `sqlite3 options.db ... 2>/dev/null` redirects all stderr to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Use something like `sed` to add the missing columns. (Ask with the `regex` tag.)

Comment: @JamesBrown that does work! I thought the `2` was a typo, but it doesn't work without it. Could you explain what the `2>` means? Thanks for helping!

Comment: `>` or `1>` redirects stdout, ie. standard output, `2>` redirects stderr or standard error to wherever you wish, in this case to null device ie. oblivion.